# How do I get the file / key size in boto S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

There must be an easy way to get the file size (key size) without pulling over a whole file.  I can see it in the Properties of the AWS S3 browser.  And I think I can get it off the "Content-length" header of a "HEAD" request.  But I'm not connecting the dots about how to do this with boto.  Extra kudos if you post a link to some more comprehensive examples than are in the [standard boto docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/).

EDIT: So the following seems to do the trick (though from looking at source code I'm not completely sure.):

```
bk = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket_name')
ky = boto.s3.key.Key(bk)
ky.open_read()  ## This sends a GET request. 
print ky.size
```

For now I'll leave the question open for comments, better solutions, or pointers to examples.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This would work:

```
bk = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket_name')
key = bk.lookup('my_key_name')
print key.size
```

The lookup method simply does a HEAD request on the bucket for the keyname so it will return all of the headers (including content-length) for the key but will not transfer any of the actual content of the key.

The [S3 tutoria](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html)l mentions this but not very explicitly and not in this exact context.  I'll add a section on this to help make it easier to find.

Note: for every old link like `http://boto.cloudhackers.com/s3_tut.html` that returns a 404, add in `"/en/latest"` right after the `".com"` : `http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html` . (Someone needs to explore mod_rewrite...)

Comment: Thanks for the response and developing Boto in the first place.  I'd be tearing out my hair without it.

Comment: I would also recommend checking "if key is None" first.

Comment: A much better place to find the boto documentation now is https://boto.readthedocs.org/

Comment: This solution uses Boto 2.x In Boto3 the API is different. See [AWS Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/migrations3.html#accessing-a-bucket)

Answer (score 79):

in **boto3**:

`s3.head_object` also performs a HEAD request to retrieve the meta data about the object:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.head_object(Bucket='bucketname', Key='keyname')
size = response['ContentLength']
```

Comment: This seems to produce incorrect results for me, I believe this is due to KMS encryption. Just something to be aware of. @satznova's Answer worked for me in this case.

Answer (score 27):

In **Boto 3**:

Using S3 `Object` you can fetch the file (a.k.a object) size in bytes. It is a resource representing the Amazon S3 Object.

In fact you can get all metadata related to the object. Like `content_length` the object size, `content_language` language the content is in, `content_encoding`, `last_modified`, etc.

```
import boto3
    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')
file_size = object.content_length  # size in bytes; ClientError if file does not exist
```

Reference [boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object)

Comment: your inline comments are not Python

Comment: happens to all of us

Comment: Just a note on `object` instantiation above. If `'key'` doesn't exist,  `object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')`  would still work... Only when executing `file_size = object.content_length` would you get a `ClientError` exception with `404` when you try to access the actual object in the bucket.

Answer (score 25):

in `boto3` using an S3 resource:

```py
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucketname).Object(keyname).content_length
```

The `head_object` call of the S3 client returned me an http "403 Forbidden"

Answer (score 7):

You can also get a list of all objects if multiple files need to be checked. For a given bucket run `list_objects_v2` and then iterate through response 'Contents'. For example:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response_contents = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket='name_of_bucket'
        ).get('Contents')
```

you'll get a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'Key': 'path/to/object1', 'LastModified': datetime, 'ETag': '"some etag"', 'Size': 2600, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, {'Key': 'path/to/object2', 'LastModified': 'datetime', 'ETag': '"some etag"', 'Size': 454, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, ... ]
```

Notice that each dictionary in the list contains 'Size' key, which is the size of your particular object. It's iterable

```
for rc in response_contents:
    print(f"Size: {rc.get('Size')}")
```

You get sizes for all files you might be interested in:

```
Size: 2600
Size: 454
Size: 2600
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of fancy answers but a pretty simple answer(which works for sure) where neither you have to perform HEAD Request nor create a resource representing the Amazon S3 Object.

Read the s3 object in the bucket properly (else object.size might not work), and use .size to read the size metadata of the file/key.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket(AWS_S3_BUCKET)
//prefix is the path following bucket_name
obj=bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix')
for key in obj:
    file_size=round(key.size*1.0/1024, 2)
    print(file_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can use the following approach

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
service_name='s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket("bucket_name")
files = []
for my_bucket_object in tq(bucket.objects.all()):
    files.append([my_bucket_object.key,my_bucket_object.size])
```

You can check size of all the keys in the bucket. please note that size is in bytes