# Calculate the size of all files in a bucket S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to calculate the size of all files that are in a S3 bucket in python and this is the code I tried so far:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'bucket-name'
prefix = 'path/to/folder'

len=0
response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket = bucket,Prefix = prefix)
for file in response['Contents']:
    name = file['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)
    len+=name['ContentLength']
```

I'm not sure  how to get the size of the file : `name['ContentLength']`
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315603/how-do-i-get-the-file-key-size-in-boto-s3) helps.

Comment: thank you but the code is this question is ambiguous

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `file['Size']` instead.
If using `list_objects` method, you have to check the value of `response['IsTruncated']` as the response will contain a maximum of 1000 objects. If `IsTruncated` is `True`, use `response['NextMarker']` as the `Prefix` to list the remaining objects in the bucket.

Or, you can use the `Bucket` class

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
total_size = 0
for k in bucket.objects.all():
    total_size += k.size
```