# Python getsize issue with S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, hdfs

I'm trying to check backuped file on our `S3 bucket` using `getsize`. 
I think it's not possible to use this function with the `s3 wrapper`.

Any alternative?

Here is my code:

```
def check_created_file(self,destination) :
    if destination != None  : 
        files = os.popen("hdfs dfs -ls %s | awk {'print $8'}"%(destination)).read().split("\n")
        files = files[1::len(files)-1]
        for file in files : 
            if  os.path.getsize(file) >  0  :
                print file 
            else: 
                print " [*] WARNING "
                print "%s is empty"%(file)
    else: 
        raise Exception("Remote dir is not specified")
```

the error I am getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: `hdfs` is not your system path and `os.popen` fails with `OSError`. Try specifying the full path to the executable, e.g. `/usr/bin/hdfs`, or better use `boto`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5498841/1869597

Comment: the fail is in the getsize function, the hdfs command is working good