# How To Use boto3 To Retrieve S3 File Size

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, filesize

I'm new to python and boto and I'm currently trying to write a dag that will check an s3 file size given the bucket location and file name. How can I take the file location (s3://bucket-info/folder/filename) and get the size of the file? If the file size is greater than 0kb, I will need to fail the job.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the file / key size in boto S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315603/how-do-i-get-the-file-key-size-in-boto-s3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use boto3 [head_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) for this

Here's something that will get you the size. Replace bucket and key with your own values:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(service_name='s3', use_ssl=True)

response = client.head_object(
    Bucket='bucketname',
    Key='full/path/to/file.jpg'
)
print(response['ContentLength'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a list of all objects if multiple files need to be checked. For a given bucket run `list_objects_v2` and then iterate through response 'Contents'. For example:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response_contents = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket='name_of_bucket'
        ).get('Contents')
```

you'll get a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'Key': 'path/to/object1', 'LastModified': datetime, 'ETag': '"some etag"', 'Size': 2600, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, {'Key': 'path/to/object2', 'LastModified': 'datetime', 'ETag': '"some etag"', 'Size': 454, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, ... ]
```

Notice that each dictionary in the list contains 'Size' key, which is the size of your particular object. It's iterable

```
for rc in response_contents:
    if rc.get('Key') == 'path/to/file':
        print(f"Size: {rc.get('Size')}")
```

You get sizes for all files you might be interested in:

```
Size: 2600
Size: 454
Size: 2600
...
```